# Move text in EditText to the right

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-edittext

I want the text in the EditText to move to the right. Becouse if not the the first leter is covered by the border of the EditText.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `android:paddingLeft="Xdp"`

Replace X with the right number to make it work good, for instance, `10dp`

Answer (score 4):

Try to increase the padding of the `EditText` in the XML. That should work.

Answer (score -2):

Use `android:gravity="right"`, That should work